# Check if string is float expressed as a decimal number only

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I'm writing script for checking if a pair of numbers is a valid coordinate. I need to check if the numbers are expressed as decimals only and in the range of 0 to 180 positive or negative for longitude and 0 to 90 positive or negative for latitude. 
I have used a try/except block to check if the number is a float like this:

```
def isFloat(n):
    try:
       float(n)
       return True
    except ValueError:
       return False
```

While this mostly works, I want it to accept floats expressed only as decimals and not values like `True`, `False`, `1e1`, `NaN`

Comment: surprisingly this is _not_ a duplicate! +1!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a fairly simple [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

def isFloat(n):
    n = str(n)  # optional; make sure you have string
    return bool(re.match(r'^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$', n))  # bool is not strictly necessary
    # ^         string beginning
    # -?        an optional -
    # \d+       followed by one or more digits (\d* if you want to allow e.g. '.95')
    # (\.\d+)?  followed by an optional group of a dot and one or more digits
    # $         string end

>>> isFloat('4')
True
>>> isFloat('4.567')
True
>>> isFloat('-4.567')
True
>>> isFloat('-4.')
False
>>> isFloat('-4.45v')
False
>>> isFloat('NaN')
False
>>> isFloat('1e1')
False
```

Comment: I would change the first `d+` to `d*` to catch values like `.985`.  Also, while I think this solution is the best for the poster's needs, it does require `n` to be (cast to) a string.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm just a novice so could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @TirthJain I added some explanation and added the link to the docs of pythons `regex` module. As for the ins and outs of regular expression syntax, you should read the docs or do a tutorial ;)

Comment: @huck_cussler I added that option in the comment, but I don't really like it as it would accept the empty string... (without further complicating the expression) As for the casting, I took it from the question's title that n is a string.